# How to create a simple TCP server with the analogRead value on Wemos D1 mini?

Tags: esp8266

I want to create a TCP server on the Wemos that serves the analogRead value of the connected potentiometer.

The code below is based on [this](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/examples/WiFiTelnetToSerial/WiFiTelnetToSerial.ino#L62) example.
The Wemos connects to the Wi-Fi and i'm able to ping it,
but the problem is that I **can't connect to the server**.
Also I don't really understand why the length of the data has to be passed with the data (`serverClients[i].write(sbuf, len);`). Why can't the library figure that out?

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

//how many clients should be able to telnet to this ESP8266
#define MAX_SRV_CLIENTS 2
const char* ssid = "myWifi";
const char* password = "myPassword";

WiFiServer server(23);
WiFiClient serverClients[MAX_SRV_CLIENTS];

unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
const long interval = 200;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.print("\nConnecting to "); Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  uint8_t i = 0;
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED && i++ < 20) delay(500);
  if (i == 21) {
    Serial.print("Could not connect to"); Serial.println(ssid);
    while (1) delay(500);
  }
  server.setNoDelay(true);
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  uint8_t i;
  //check if there are any new clients
  if (server.hasClient()) {
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_SRV_CLIENTS; i++) {
      //find free/disconnected spot
      if (!serverClients[i] || !serverClients[i].connected()) {
        if (serverClients[i]) serverClients[i].stop();
        serverClients[i] = server.available();
        continue;
      }
    }
    //no free/disconnected spot so reject
    WiFiClient serverClient = server.available();
    serverClient.stop();
  }

  //do every 200ms
  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
    previousMillis = currentMillis;

    int isensorValue = analogRead(A0); //analog read
    String sSensorValue = String(isensorValue); //int to string
    size_t len = sSensorValue.length();
    uint8_t sbuf[len];
    sSensorValue.getBytes(sbuf, len);
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_SRV_CLIENTS; i++) {
      if (serverClients[i] && serverClients[i].connected()) {
        serverClients[i].write(sbuf, len);
        delay(1);
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: I've never used a Wemos, but if you compare to the code you linked, you seem to be missing a `server.begin()` call.

Comment: Also, that code looks a little wonky to me. For example, the `continue` is completely useless. Did they want a `break` there?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp You have a great eye for detail!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem was that I forgot the following line.
Thanks to @Johnny Mopp for pointing this out.

```
server.begin()
```

**Correct code:**

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

//how many clients should be able to telnet to this ESP8266
#define MAX_SRV_CLIENTS 2
const char* ssid = "myWifi";
const char* password = "myPassword";

WiFiServer server(23);
WiFiClient serverClients[MAX_SRV_CLIENTS];

unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
const long interval = 200;
void setup() {
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  uint8_t i = 0;
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED && i++ < 20) delay(500);
  if (i == 21) {
    Serial.print("Could not connect to"); Serial.println(ssid);
    while (1) delay(500);
  }
  server.begin();
  server.setNoDelay(true);
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  uint8_t i;
  //check if there are any new clients
  if (server.hasClient()) {
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_SRV_CLIENTS; i++) {
      //find free/disconnected spot
      if (!serverClients[i] || !serverClients[i].connected()) {
        if (serverClients[i]) serverClients[i].stop();
        serverClients[i] = server.available();
        continue;
      }
    }
    //no free/disconnected spot so reject
    WiFiClient serverClient = server.available();
    serverClient.stop();
  }

  //do every 200ms
  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
    previousMillis = currentMillis;

    int isensorValue = analogRead(A0);
    String sSensorValue = String(isensorValue) + "\n\r";
    size_t len = sSensorValue.length();
    uint8_t sbuf[len];
    sSensorValue.getBytes(sbuf, len);
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_SRV_CLIENTS; i++) {
      if (serverClients[i] && serverClients[i].connected()) {
        serverClients[i].write(sbuf, len);
        delay(1);
      }
    }

  }
}
```